# Updating pixel size tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to update the pixel size of my grid once I press the zoom in or zoom out buttons. When I click on the zoom in, the pixel size should increase it's size by one, when  I zoom out, the pixel size should decrease by 1. I'm having trouble updating the grid without deleting what has been drawn in it. This is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser
import math

PixelSize = 10


class Grilla:
    colorCelda = "black"
    colorDefault = "white"
    colorBorde = "black"
    bordeDefault = "black"

    def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size = size
        self.fill = False

    def switch(self):
        self.fill = not self.fill

    def reset(self):
        self.fill = False

    def draw(self):
        if self.master is not None:

            outline = Grilla.colorBorde
            fill = Grilla.colorCelda

            if not self.fill:
                outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
                fill = Grilla.colorDefault

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.square_clicked)
        self.cellSize = tamGrid

        self.pen = "draw"

        self._grid = []

        for row in range(numFil):

            line = []
            for column in range(numCol):
                line.append(Grilla(master, self, column, row, tamGrid))

            self._grid.append(line)

        self.switched = []

        self.draw()

    def square_clicked(self, event):
        row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
        cell = self._grid[row][column]
        if self.pen == "draw":
            cell.switch()
            if cell.fill:
                self.switched.append(cell)
            else:
                self.switched.remove(cell)

        cell.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _coordenadas(self, event):
        row = event.y // self.cellSize
        column = event.x // self.cellSize
        return row, column

    def switch_to_draw(self):
        self.pen = "draw"

    def color(self):
        colorSelec = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
        if colorSelec:
            Grilla.colorCelda = colorSelec
            Grilla.colorBorde = colorSelec

    def clear(self):
        self.switched = []
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.reset()
                cell.draw()

    def DDA(self):

        x1 = self.switched[0].abs
        x2 = self.switched[1].abs
        y1 = self.switched[0].ord
        y2 = self.switched[1].ord
        length = abs(x2 - x1) if abs(x2 - x1) > abs(y2 - y1) else abs(y2 - y1)
        dx = abs(x1 - x2) / float(length)
        dy = abs(y1 - y2) / float(length)

        x, y = x1, y1

        for i in range(length):
            if x1 < x2:
                x += dx
            else:
                x -= dx

            if y1 < y2:
                y += dy
            else:
                y -= dy

            cell = self._grid[int(y)][int(x)]
            cell.switch()
            cell.draw()

    def bresenhamLine(self):
        x1 = self.switched[0].abs
        x2 = self.switched[1].abs
        y1 = self.switched[0].ord
        y2 = self.switched[1].ord

        dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1
        D = 2 * dy - dx
        x, y = x1, y1

        for x in range(x1 + 1, x2 + 1):
            if D > 0:
                y += 1
                D += (2 * dy - 2 * dx)
            else:
                D += 2 * dy

            cell = self._grid[int(y)][int(x)]
            cell.switch()
            cell.draw()

    def bresenhamCircle(self):
        x1 = self.switched[0].abs
        x2 = self.switched[1].abs
        y1 = self.switched[0].ord
        y2 = self.switched[1].ord

        radius = int(math.sqrt(math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)))

        x = 0
        y = radius
        switch = 3 - (2 * radius)

        self.dibujarCirculo(x1, y1, x, y)
        while x <= y:
            x = x + 1
            if switch < 0:
                switch = switch + (4 * x) + 6
            else:
                switch = switch + (4 * (x - y)) + 10
                y = y - 1
            self.dibujarCirculo(x1, y1, x, y)

    def dibujarCirculo(self, xc, yc, x, y):
        self.drawPoint(xc + x, yc + y)
        self.drawPoint(xc + x, yc - y)
        self.drawPoint(xc + y, yc + x)
        self.drawPoint(xc + y, yc - x)
        self.drawPoint(xc - x, yc + y)
        self.drawPoint(xc - x, yc - y)
        self.drawPoint(xc - y, yc + x)
        self.drawPoint(xc - y, yc - x)

    def drawPoint(self, x, y):
        cell = self._grid[int(y)][int(x)]
        cell.switch()
        cell.draw()

    def Ellipse(self):
        x1 = self.switched[0].abs
        x2 = self.switched[1].abs
        y1 = self.switched[0].ord
        y2 = self.switched[1].ord

        radius = int(math.sqrt(math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)))
        x = 0
        y = radius
        switch = 3 - (2 * radius)

        self.dibujarElipse(x1, y1, x, y)
        while x <= y:
            x = x + 1
            if switch < 0:
                switch = switch + (4 * x) + 6
            else:
                switch = switch + (4 * (x - y)) + 10
                y = y - 1
            self.dibujarElipse(x1, y1, x, y)

    def dibujarElipse(self, xc, yc, x, y):
        self.drawPoint(xc + x, yc + y)
        self.drawPoint(xc + x, yc - y)
        self.drawPoint(xc + y, yc + x)
        self.drawPoint(xc + y, yc - x)
        self.drawPoint(xc - x, yc + y)
        self.drawPoint(xc - x, yc - y)
        self.drawPoint(xc - y, yc + x)
        self.drawPoint(xc - y, yc - x)

    def zoomIn(self):
        global PixelSize
        if PixelSize >= 10:
            PixelSize = PixelSize + 1


    def zoomOut(self):
        global PixelSize
        if PixelSize > 11:
            PixelSize = PixelSize - 1


    # def floodFill(self, grid, fila, columna, nuevoColor):
    #     color = grid[fila][columna]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()

    grid = CellGrilla(app, 75, 75, PixelSize)

    grid.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="news")

    colorBoton = Button(app, text="Elegir color", command=grid.color, height=1, width=30)
    ddaBoton = Button(app, text="DDA", command=grid.DDA, height=1, width=30)
    zoomInBoton = Button(app, text="Zoom in", command=grid.zoomIn, height=1, width=30)
    zoomOutBoton = Button(app, text="Zoom out", command=grid.zoomOut, height=1, width=30)
    reset_btn = Button(app, text="Borrar", command=grid.clear, height=1, width=30)
    BresenhamLine = Button(app, text="Bresenham Line", command=grid.bresenhamLine, height=1, width=30)
    BresenhamCircle = Button(app, text="Bresenham Circle", command=grid.bresenhamCircle, height=1, width=30)
    Ellipse = Button(app, text="Elipse", command=grid.bresenhamCircle, height=1, width=30)
    # FloodFill = Button(app, text="Rellenar", command=grid.bresenhamCircle, height=1, width=30)

    zoomInBoton.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="news")
    zoomOutBoton.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="news")
    colorBoton.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="news")
    ddaBoton.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="news")
    reset_btn.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="news")
    BresenhamLine.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="news")
    BresenhamCircle.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="news")
    Ellipse.grid(row=4, column =3, sticky="news")
    # FloodFill.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="news")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] the illustrates the problem — not your whole program.

Comment: Ideally you should create a new, minimal program that does only what you're trying to do and no more.

Comment: You don't need to delete the rectangles and recreate them.  Just update their coordinates using `canvas.coords()` when zoom in and out.

Comment: I've tried updating the grid with grid.update() and also the canvas.coords(), I get error message with canvas.coords. I printed out the values of PixelSize and it is increasing and decreasing.